# Java enum ordinal returning -1?

Tags: java, enums, ordinal

Alright so I'm currently writing some code for a project I'm working on, and I decided an Enum for data storage will be my best bet. But in the first time in my life, the enum.ordinal() returns -1?

Heres the code:

```
            DuelRules.Rules rule = DuelRules.Rules.values()[(buttonId - (buttonId < 29 ? 18 : 19))];
            if (buttonId == 29) {
                rule = DuelRules.Rules.POCKET;
            }
            System.out.println(rule + ", " + rule.ordinal());
            rules.swapRule(player, other, rule);
            reset(false);
```

This statement here:

```
System.out.println(rule + ", " + rule.ordinal());
```

It prints the correct rule value, but when it prints rule.ordinal() it is printing -1?

Example:

```
HAT, -1
```

My Enum:

```
public enum Rules {
    HAT(5000, 1),
    CAPE(5000, 2),
    AMULET(5000, 4),
    WEAPON(5000, 8),
    BODY(5000, 16),
    SHIELD(5000, 32),
    LEG(5000, 128),
    GLOVE(5000, 512),
    BOOT(5000, 1024),
    RING(5000, 4096),
    ARROW(5000, 8192),
    POCKET(17837, 1),

    FORFEIT(4989),
    MOVEMENT(4990),
    RANGE(4991),
    MELEE(4992),
    MAGIC(4993),
    DRINKS(4994),
    FOOD(4995),
    PRAYER(4996),
    OBSTACLES(4997),
    FUN_WEAPONS(4998),
    NO_ABILITIES(4999),
    SUMMONING(5001);

    private final int varbitId;
    private final int value;

    private Rules(int id, int... value) {
        this.varbitId = id;
        this.value = value.length > 0 ? value[0] : 0;
    }

}
```

Note, that enum is inside of another class, not sure if that can effect the outcome. Thanks for your help, I'm completely lost with this one.

EDIT: Upon farther review I found that the ordinal is being changed by passing it as an argument?

Screnshot of console:

[image]

Code:

```
        } else if (buttonId >= 18 && buttonId <= 42) {
           DuelRules.Rules rule = DuelRules.Rules.values()[(buttonId - (buttonId < 29 ? 18 : 19))];
            System.out.println("Point one: "+rule + ", " + rule.ordinal());

            rules.swapRule(player, other, rule);

            getDuel(other).rules.setRules(player, other, rules
                    .rules);
            reset(false);
            sendFlash(interfaceId, buttonId);
        }
```

Where it prints Point one, the Rule and its .ordinal is correct, in this case OBSTACLES, 20

But where it passes the rule paramters in rules.swapRule, it changes the ordinal to -1?

```
public boolean swapRule(Player player, Player other, Rules rule) {
    System.out.println("Point 2(swapRule): " + rule + ", " + rule.ordinal());
}
```

What is causing the Rule parameters to be changes when getting passed as an argument?

Comment: *Most programmers will have no use for this method. It is designed for use by sophisticated enum-based data structures, such as EnumSet and EnumMap* (from [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal%28%29)). Using enums when you need to work with element indices is a bad practice.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Please post a complete and reproducible example.

Comment: I'm voting to close. What you're describing goes against the javadoc for `Enum#ordinal()` and you still haven't provided proof.

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce the problem within a smaller project. The project which contains this code is > 8gb. I can't seem to re-produce the problem in an almost exact same scenario in a blank project. I'm not sure what to do next because .ordinal should NEVER return -1.

Comment: Change the line to `System.out.println("This is an experiment: " + rule + ", " + rule.ordinal());` then post a screenshot of the output This is an experiment: HAT, -1. The most logical explanation is that the output HAT, -1 is actually being produced by a different line in your code.

Comment: Alright so I was able to narrow the problem and updated the OP.

Comment: It's seems the issue is fixed when I moved the Rules enum outside of the DuelRules class. Not sure why this fixed it, judging that Enum.ordinal() should NEVER return -1. Thanks anyways!

Comment: I know you probably don't care any more, as the problem has gone away. But I'm fascinated by this. It's the strangest question I've ever seen. Is it possible to post the entire class DuelRules up?

Comment: When you see code for an RSPS end up on SO :)

Answer (score 2):

Your approah defeats the sheer purpose of using an enumerator. Instead of mangling with indices you could use the Enum directly like this

```
button.setActionCommand (Rules.HAT.toString ());
```

Then in your ActoinListener you can determine which button was clicked by using this

```
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
    if (Rule.valueOf (e.getActionCommand()) == Rules.HAT) {
        //HAT related button was called, process it
    }
}
```

Comment: You're missing the point. We may all be able to improve the OP's code, but the fact is that it should be completely impossible for the line `System.out.println(rule + ", " + rule.ordinal());` to produce HAT, -1. Either the OP is mistaken, or there's something seriously wrong.

Comment: I am just proposing an alternative better suited to the purpose of Enumerations. Moreover, I think someone should have done it at least for other people who can get to this question via Google so that people see what better alernatives exist.  Don't agree with the down vote sorry

Comment: I agree. This is the correct answer. OP should not be messing around under the hood.

Comment: `Enum.name()` would be better than potentially-overridden `Enum.toString()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get this result by reflection:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Main {

    enum Fruit { APPLE }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Field field = Fruit.class.getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("ordinal");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            field.set(Fruit.APPLE, -1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        System.out.println(Fruit.APPLE + ", " + Fruit.APPLE.ordinal());
    }
}
```

However I doubt anyone could do this by mistake.